# Multi-steps forecasting using Keras TimeSeries leads to loss NaN

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

Here my problem (I guess it is quite generic):

I have 4 times series (x1, x2, x3, x4) and based on the 'd' historical data
[(x_1 (t-d), x_2 (t-d), x_3 (t-d), x_4 (t-d),..., (x_1 (t-1), x_2 (t-1), x_3 (t-1), x_4 (t-1)]
I would like to forecast [x_1 (t), x_1 (t+1)]

So, after loading my data which are complete and without any NaN, I have first use Scikit-Learn MinMaxScaler (feature_range= (0, 1) to rescale them.

Then, I have split them between Train and Test sets, and use Keras TimeSeries method with batch_size = 72

```
train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data_train, target_train,
                           start_index=1,
                           length=n_lags, sampling_rate=1,
                           batch_size=batch_size)

test_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data_test, target_test,
                           start_index=1,
                           length=n_lags, sampling_rate=1,
                           batch_size=batch_size)
```

The shape of the Train (input, target) is
Train X, y shapes per batch (72, 10, 4) (72, 2)
the same for the Test
Test X, y shapes per batch (72, 10, 4) (72, 2)

For instance here are the first input data of the first batch (train_gen[0][0][:3]):

```
array([[[0.28665611, 0.63705857, 0.32643516, 0.45493102],
        [0.26487018, 0.6301432 , 0.30965767, 0.45791034],
        [0.25228031, 0.61725465, 0.3161332 , 0.45023995],
        [0.24793654, 0.58854431, 0.32644507, 0.43765143],
        [0.25025404, 0.55537186, 0.33264606, 0.42989095],
        [0.25923045, 0.53953228, 0.32621582, 0.43297785],
        [0.27078601, 0.53333689, 0.31391997, 0.4531239 ],
        [0.28204362, 0.55253638, 0.30399583, 0.48110336],
        [0.2905511 , 0.59113979, 0.29693304, 0.50782682],
        [0.29877746, 0.65041821, 0.28764287, 0.53247815]],

       [[0.26487018, 0.6301432 , 0.30965767, 0.45791034],
        [0.25228031, 0.61725465, 0.3161332 , 0.45023995],
        [0.24793654, 0.58854431, 0.32644507, 0.43765143],
        [0.25025404, 0.55537186, 0.33264606, 0.42989095],
        [0.25923045, 0.53953228, 0.32621582, 0.43297785],
        [0.27078601, 0.53333689, 0.31391997, 0.4531239 ],
        [0.28204362, 0.55253638, 0.30399583, 0.48110336],
        [0.2905511 , 0.59113979, 0.29693304, 0.50782682],
        [0.29877746, 0.65041821, 0.28764287, 0.53247815],
        [0.30240836, 0.71207879, 0.34604287, 0.54785854]],

       [[0.25228031, 0.61725465, 0.3161332 , 0.45023995],
        [0.24793654, 0.58854431, 0.32644507, 0.43765143],
        [0.25025404, 0.55537186, 0.33264606, 0.42989095],
        [0.25923045, 0.53953228, 0.32621582, 0.43297785],
        [0.27078601, 0.53333689, 0.31391997, 0.4531239 ],
        [0.28204362, 0.55253638, 0.30399583, 0.48110336],
        [0.2905511 , 0.59113979, 0.29693304, 0.50782682],
        [0.29877746, 0.65041821, 0.28764287, 0.53247815],
        [0.30240836, 0.71207879, 0.34604287, 0.54785854],
        [0.30113961, 0.7603975 , 0.4250553 , 0.55976262]]])
```

And the corresponding target array (train_gen[0][1][:3]):

```
array([[0.30240836, 0.30113961],
       [0.30113961, 0.30203943],
       [0.30203943, 0.31435152]])
```

Now my model is very simple using Keras library

```
h = LSTM(50)(inputs)
output = Dense(2)(h)
model = Model(inputs,output)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

And the problem comes when I start the training:

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen,
                              epochs=50,
                              validation_data=test_gen,
                              shuffle=False)
Epoch 1/50
40/40 [==============================] - 5s 120ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/50
40/40 [==============================] - 1s 37ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/50
40/40 [==============================] - 2s 39ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

Notice the "nan" which appears at each epoch (at the end of the epoch by the way).

Can anyone give me some hints on how to find the problem? I should mention that when the output (i.e. the target) is just (x1 (t) then the learning is OK and the train loss and the test loss converge smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have found the source of my problem: this comes from the fact that before using TimeseriesGenerator using data_train for instance, I have to use the following code to produce the {x1(t), x1(t+1)} targets

```
target_train = np.transpose(np.stack((data_train[:,0],
                                  shift(data_train[:,0],-1,cval=np.NaN))))
```

But, then the last entrie is something like that ([0.18358087, nan]) so the computation of the loss is corupted by this last entry.

The solution is just to remove it.